# Simple Question about how Tableau Desktop talks to a very large database

Tags: sql, database, odata, tableau-api, business-intelligence

I am just curious, as to how Tableau talks to a large data source- for example if I have a data source that has 1.4 million records, and I make a  simple table with this data, maybe a graph etc, then how does tableau get this data? Does it go query the data source, ask the data source how much it has, then pull in the first 10,000, does it go back and retrieve the next 10k etc? or does it do it in one go? Also I want to know where Tableau stores this data it receives?

Hope my question makes sense - Just trying to understand the underlying mechanisms. 
Thank you!

Comment: You can find out by running your databases monitoring tool and seeing what SQL is submitted. Reporting tools are usually smart enough to submit efficient SQL. But of for example you are combining two completely different data sources, yes it probably has to extract all data and combine within the tableau server.

Comment: Would you mind suggesting a tool I can use?Thanks

Comment: It depends on the database. In SQL Server you can use SQL Profiler or DMV's or my favourite is `sp_WhoIsActive`. Do you have a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I am using odata- as a connection, and I am unsure how Tableau is querying the data? It seems to me that simply puts not limit on the calls its making to the odata serve-so if I had 4 million customers, it will simply go query the odata endpoint and bring me back 4million? thats not how excel power query works, it limits how much its going to call, and if you want more it will simply buffer go back to the data base and give you the next 1000 or so etc..so essentially isnt Tableau being a bit 'silly' my doing this? or inefficient?

Comment: As I understand it, Odata is different to your average relational database. It’s over the web so it’s quite different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau can work with external data sources in more than one way. You can extract the entire DB content to a local file (called an extract) or you can have a live connection to the database.

If the connection is live, then Tableau sends the DB queries designed to return the data you want not the entire content of the DB. So if you have 1.4m records containing, say, a full year's sales information and you want monthly totals, Tableau will send a query asking the DB to return the monthly totals. This will result in just 12 numbers being returned to Tableau: the DB itself will do the work and Tableau doesn't need to pull 1.4m numbers and add them up. This is how most data sources work: the user requests a result (using SQL queries) and the DB works out how to return that result. This means you don't need to copy the entire database every time you want to add some numbers up.

Live queries won't *sample* the database: the answers you get will usually be the correct totals (though some sources like Google's BigQuery will use sampling for some statistical aggregates unless told otherwise).

Both Tableau and many databases will cache the results of queries done recently so the results will be faster. Tableau's results will be held locally.